# Wordpress not reading embed code

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I installed this plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-responsive-video-embedder/screenshots/) to make the size of the vídeos on my wordpress site responsive.

However, i'm having a problem. When i put embed code like this "[youtube id=vrXgLhkv21Y mode=normal]" on the default text widget that comes with wordpress nothing happens, the codeis shown on the site like text.

Can this be a problem of the plugin or is something with my wordpress site for not reading this tags? Plugins conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcodes don't work in widgets by default.  You can however add shortcode functionality to your widgets by adding the following to your `functions.php` file.

```
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');
```

You should then be able to use shortcodes in WordPress' default text widget.

Comment: Thanks a lot Ryan, added that line to functions.php on my child theme and it worked like a charm. It's reading now :P

Can i make you another question related with Wordpress so that i don't need to open a question for that?

Comment: If your second question is unrelated to this one, you should probably start a new question.  That way if someone else is looking for an answer to your second question, it will be easier for them to find it.  After you post it, you can send me a link and I'll take a look though!

Comment: Ok, here goes then:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617400/responsive-plugin-for-wordpress